# How do I configure upstart to run a script on shutdown when the process takes longer than 10secs?

Tags: shutdown, upstart

I am running ubuntu 11.10 in a virtual machine (VirtualBox) to learn more about development in linux. I am using a git repository to save my work and have written a script to bundle my work up and save it to the shared folder for use while the virtual machine is not running.

I would like to automatically run this script before shutdown so that my work is always available if the vm is off (currently I have to manually run the script).

I don't know if upstart is the best way to accomplish this, but this is the config that I wrote as a test:

```
description     "test script to run at shutdown"

start on runlevel [056]

task

script
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/start
sleep 15
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/start-long
end script

pre-start script
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/pre-start
sleep 15
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/pre-start-long
end script

post-start script
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/post-start
sleep 15
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/post-start-long
end script

pre-stop script
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/pre-stop
sleep 15
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/pre-stop-long
end script

post-stop script
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/post-stop
sleep 15
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/post-stop-long
end script
```

The result is that only one touch is accomplished (the first touch in pre-start).
What do I need to change to see one of the touches after the sleep to work?
Or Is there an easier way to get this accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practices](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) has a great number of code snippets to use in creating upstart tasks and jobs.

The [shutdown process](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#shutdown-process) section of the cookbook says that `/etc/init/rc.conf` will be run and call `/etc/init.d/rc`. In turn this will eventually call `/etc/init.d/sendsigs`. So if you `start on starting rc` then your task will be executed before rc (and the sigterms that would normally have the process shut down).

file: /etc/init/test.conf

```
description "test script to run at shutdown"

start on starting rc
task
exec /etc/init/test.sh
```

file: /etc/init/test.sh

```
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/start
sleep 15
touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/start-long
```

Comment: Added a concrete example to this question, but it doesn't work (only the first touch is run on shutdown) even though the documentation in [Create an Event Alias](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#create-an-event-alias) says that it should. Please look at it an see if I made an error.

Comment: Tiris, this should work. I'd be interested in seeing your /var/log/syslog after the reboot, particularly to see if test's process was forcibly killed by upstart.

Comment: The latest edit of this answer does work. Check the revision history to see the problem child. I guess I should have commented that I made an edit(or is it more proper to remove the comment and add a new one?Is there a stackexchange etiquette?). I would be interested in knowing why the problem child doesn't work (since the documentation says it should).

Comment: What exactly does the test.conf file mean? Do I make a file called test.conf, or do I add this to rc.conf?

Comment: @heneryville `test.conf` is just a random filename. You could just as easily use `whatEverYouWant.conf`. Your comment also shows that you didn't read the "Cookbook" mentioned in the answer. If you look in section 4.2 the Job Configuration File is more thoroughly explained.

Comment: This will run at more than just shutdown.  You need to add `RUNLEVEL=0` to catch only shutdown or `RUNLEVEL=[06]` to catch shutdown and reboot.  In either case, that would go right after `starting rc`

Comment: This worked for me on Amazon Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I think this cannot be done via *upstart*, as the **/etc/init.d/sendsigs** script, which is invoked by *upstart* when halting/restarting, kills all processes (`killall5 -9`) within 10 seconds, and even if that does not succeed, it goes for unmounting everything and shutdown.

The best way would be to use the rusty **/etc/init.d** style scripts.

Example: **/etc/init.d/shutdown_job**

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          shutdown_job
# Required-Start:    
# Required-Stop:     sendsigs
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: bla
# Description: 
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_stop () {
    date > /root/s.log
    sleep 20
    date >> /root/s.log
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    # No-op
    ;;
  restart|reload|force-reload)
    echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
  stop)
    do_stop
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

Then activate the script

```
sudo update-rc.d shutdown_job start 19 0 6 .
```

This will put the script before the *sendsigs* script on runlevels 0 a 6 (shutdown, reboot). This sample script will record the date, then sleep for 20 secs, then record the date again to */root/s.log*.)

More info:

- `man update-rc.d`
- http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-sysvinit

Comment: I am not at all familiar with doing this sort of thing. Is there a good guide on getting this to work? Please edit with more info.

Comment: I tried this out and it doesn't work (well not exactly). I added a `touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/start` and `touch /media/sf_LinuxEducation/start-long` right next to the date commands. The dates are logged, but the touches are not touched. This makes me wonder if that drive is unmounted at the time the script is run.

I think it may have something to do with the NN argument, though I am not sure really how this argument works (the man page explains it in a very mind bending way). How do you know what number (or pair of numbers) should be set in this argument?

Comment: Scripts get executed as per their numbers as seen when you list the `/etc/rc6.d` directory. So the **19** shutdown script should have been executed before any unmounting is done (>31). But why not try your hypothesis and touch a file in `/root` instead?

Comment: Looking in the dir `/etc/rc6.d` reveals that the the shared folders are being mounted/unmounted with the `K70vboxadd` script. Would changing the NN argument (for my script) to 71 get my script to run before the unmount of VB shared folders? I will try it later today.

Comment: Well that didn't work.
**Update:** I added a `touch /root/start` before the `sleep 20` command and no file is created. I don't even know where to begin to find out why. The dates are happily added to the `/root/s.log` file why can I not touch a file?