# shell script to set time and date on ubuntu

Tags: scripts

my desktop CMOS battery is not working, therefore I have to set time and date each time my computer starts up. I want to create a shell script to automate the setting of date and time on my computer after each boot is complete.
options that exist include:
 1. buying a CMOS battery :- am considering this, but for the meantime a
    shell script will do.
 2. using NTP to synchronize time and date with
    internet servers :- am not connected to the internet.

Comment: How your desktop is supposed to know the time? If it has no clock nor internet... ;-) Please specify more, maybe you need a script to ask you to enter the time/date at every boot?

Comment: How do you plan on syncing with NTP servers if you're not connected to the internet?

Comment: @Rmano the shell script could calculate the date dynamically, depending on the saved date when the computer was shut down last. the date must not be that accurate

Answer (score 0):

If the system has no way to know the hour, the only thing you can do is trying to save the date-time on shutdown and reload on reboot (as you suggested).

**Warning**: The following instruction should work with a SystemV-type init system: I have not tested it (I am on a windows machine now) so you have to test them and take them with a bit of salt --- there could be typos.

**Warning2** I think that [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) (the modern Ubuntu implementation of init scripts) respect it, but your mileage can vary: test and experiments are needed.You can start from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78298/how-do-i-configure-upstart-to-run-a-script-on-shutdown-when-the-process-takes-lo) if you want to do it in a fancier way.

To save the date on shutdown/reboot, you can add a script to the `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d` directory (the first used for shutdown and the latter for reboot). The normal way to do it is to create the script in `/etc/init.d` and then link the script from there.

All the following commands must be issued as root. Use your preferred method...

So you can create a script `/etc/init.d/savedatetime` with your favorite editor and the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S > /root/lastseendate.txt
```

make it executable and then link it (the `date` format is the one that date is able to read-back, see `man date`).

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/savedatetime
cd /etc/rc0.d/
ln -s ../init.d/savedatetime K99savedatetime
cd /etc/rc6.d/
ln -s ../init.d/savedatetime K99savedatetime
```

The `K99` should make this script the last one executed before shutdown or reboot. If the clock is maintained through a reboot and you want do that only on shutdown, simply skip the last two commands.

Then at reboot you want to read the file. There are a lot of place where to put it, the easiest being `/etc/rc.local`.

Edit it and put near the start:

```
[ -f  /root/lastseendate.txt ] && date $(cat /root/lastseendate.txt) 
rm -f /root/lastseendate.txt
```

...and that should be it. Happy hacking!