# How do I get my script to run BEFORE any shutdown sequence like unmounting my external drive

Tags: scripts, 15.10, shutdown, upstart, systemd

I have a back up script in `~/scripts/backup.sh` and my upstart conf in `~/.config/upstart/shutdown.conf`.

```
description "my shutdown script"
start on desktop-end

task
console log
script
  exec ~/scripts/backup.sh start
end script
```

My script backs up to an external hard drive `on desktop-end` but the external hard drive gets unmounted before my script is called.

**How can I precede the shutdown sequence with my script and then resume only when my script is done**?

I tried the solution from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/78324/206820) post but the hook `on starting rc` isn't working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit to this [posted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1016848/587953)

First, I don't know why upstart works at all since Ubuntu 15.10 should be using systemd instead.  So I used systemd to solve my problem.

I create a systemd "unit" called backup.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup script
DefaultDependencies=no
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/D21EF5DA1EF5B795 /home /media/external
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target


[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/deanresin/scripts/backup.sh start
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`RequiresMountsFor` ensures those hard drives remain mounted before and during the script.  `Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target` is the hook that will call the backup script.

Put the backup.service file in /etc/systemd/system and `sudo chmod u+x /etc/systemd/system/backup.service` to make it executable.

Now enable the backup.service by `systemctl enable backup.service`

And voila!  The backup script "backup.sh" should be called at restart,shutdown or halt and executed before the specified drives are unmounted.