# Ubuntu is not shutting down

Tags: shutdown, webdav, davfs2

I added a WebDAV folder to `/etc/fstab`

```
https://my.owncloud.de/remote.php/dav/files/matt/ /home/matt/Owncloud davfs user,rw,auto 0 0
```

but when it's mounted then Ubuntu doesn't shut down. See more details in the attached image.

[image: Shutdown]

Comment: Unmounting it before the shutdown does not work?

Comment: Unmounting before shutdown work's but I don't want to always unmounting it myself. I want that it's mounted automatically on boot and unmounted on shutdown.

Comment: so you add it to the system so it is executed before a shutdown. See for insrance https://askubuntu.com/questions/779154/how-do-i-get-my-script-to-run-before-any-shutdown-sequence-like-unmounting-my-ex

Comment: Thx now it's shutting down well

Comment: could you make what you did an answer and accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a custom script for unmount

   `nano /home/matt/Scripts/umountCloud.sh`
2. Add unmount command

   `umount /home/matt/Owncloud`
3. Make it executable

   `chmod +x /home/matt/Scripts/umountCloud.sh`
4. Create a systems script

   `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/preShutdown.service`
5. Add following lines to execute the custom script on shutdown

   [Unit] Description=Shutdown Process

   [Service] Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/home/matthias/Scripts/umountCloud.sh

   [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target